# Border top styling (linear gradient)

Tags: css

I have an image on which I have added a top border of 20px.
I want to color that top-border in a way that it shows a linear gradient.
I have tried in different ways without success.

Could you guys help me out? This is the code (html and css):

```
<div class="logo"><img src="images/tiger.jpg"></div>

.logo img {width:100%;top-border:20px solid;}
```

Comment: What different ways have you tried? Your question should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, so please include the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help you find where the problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this. I have made border to use `before` class.

```css
.logo{position:relative;width:200px;}
img{
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
.logo:before{
  /* IE10+ */ 
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ffb76b 0%, #FF7C00 51%, #ff7f04 100%);

  /* Mozilla Firefox */ 
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ffb76b 0%, #FF7C00 51%, #ff7f04 100%);

  /* Opera */ 
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ffb76b 0%, #FF7C00 51%, #ff7f04 100%);

  /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #ffb76b), color-stop(51, #FF7C00), color-stop(100, #ff7f04));

  /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffb76b 0%, #FF7C00 51%, #ff7f04 100%);

  /* W3C Markup */ 
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffb76b 0%, #FF7C00 51%, #ff7f04 100%);
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff&text=sample+image" alt=""></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a colored top border like this;

```
border-top: 20px solid #cccccc;
```

Instead of **#cccccc**, you can give the desired color